# Excel - Avoid counting 0's when creating a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, countif

On my spreadsheet I am using a formula which will give me a 0 if the criteria are not met

```
(=SUM(IF(F:F="Customer",0.5,0),(IF(G:G="Customer",0.5,0))
```

When I create my pivot to do a count of customer, it is counting the zeros within the column. I have tried `COUNTIF` but that seems not to work with a formula inside of it, only when there is a static value.

Hoping for an answer that is better than me having to replace all the zeros.

Thank you,
WHC

Comment: Have a helper column in source that says =IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(targetCell)),targetCell=0),"Exclude","Include")  then put that field in the pagefield area of the pivot and filter on Include?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the unwanted values like this: Click on the small dropdown next to col2 in the fields list

[image]

Comment: The only problem with using this method is that I have a graph attached to the pivot table. When any changes are made to the graph then all information is included (e.g. I want to show the top 10 results).

Comment: If you have created the pivot chart using the same pivot table then the changes should be reflected in both